# Can Only Connect to Mysql 8 on macOS when Port is Specified

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I have mysql 8.0.12 installed on macOS High Sierra (10.13.6):

```
$ brew info mysql
mysql: stable 8.0.12 (bottled)
Open source relational database management system
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/
Conflicts with:
  ...
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12 (255 files, 233.0MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-09-04 at 11:09:42
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/mysql.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✔
Required: openssl ✔
==> Requirements
Required: macOS >= 10.10 ✔
==> Options
...
```

This is the contents of my `my.cnf` file:

```
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

The issue is when I start mysql via homebrew services:

```
brew services start mysql
```

and check that it is running:

```
$ brew services list
Name  Status  User Plist
mysql started jhl  /Users/jhl/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist

$ ps aux | grep mysql
jhl               8609   0.0  0.0  4267768    900 s004  S+   11:21AM 0:00.00 grep mysql
jhl               8364   0.0  2.2  4896156 367368   ??  S    11:18AM   0:00.96 /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/opt/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=jhls-MacBook-Pro.local.err --pid-file=jhls-MacBook-Pro.local.pid
jhl               8275   0.0  0.0  4282688   1300   ??  S    11:18AM   0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql
jhl               4558   0.0  0.0  4298668   3352 s000  S+   11:01AM   0:00.04 view /usr/local/var/mysql/jhls-MacBook-Pro.local.err

$ lsof -i :3306
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  8364  jhl   19u  IPv4 0xb949031a3ab21e7b      0t0  TCP localhost:mysql (LISTEN)
```

I cannot connect to `mysqld` with the default options:

```
$ mysql -uroot
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (61)
```

I always have to specify the port:

```
$ mysql -uroot -P 3306
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.12 Homebrew
...
mysql>
```

This works fine on the command line, but I'm having no luck when it comes to trying to connect to other database tools, such as the database window inside RubyMine. I've reinstalled mysql (version 8) and mysql version 5.7 multiple times from homebrew (making sure to do a [full uninstallation](https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d) each time) and this problem still seems to persist on all versions I attempt to use, which makes me think it is a network problem. I've even tried specifying the `port` in both the `[client]` and `[mysqld]` sections of `my.cnf`, but have had no luck.

Comment: Do you have a port specified in `~/.my.cnf`?

Comment: Ah, that was it! It was specifying port 3360 (typo). Thank you so much!